# List specific files in command that expects `ls` piped into it

Tags: pipe, posix

I'm looking for an elegant cross-compatible way to direct the names of files into `entr`. I know the following works with Bash, but I'd like a command that would work in other shells.

(`entr` is a program that watches files and runs a command on start and when those files change. Its documentation shows `ls *.ext`, for example, piped into it - so it is expecting a newline separated list of legitimate filenames piped to it. It warns on bad filenames.)

### multiliners

This command lets me list specific files with a multiline herestring:

```bsh
$ entr echo "command ran" <<< "
> filename1
> filename2
> "
```

I find the quotation marks and having to list them on separate lines to be annoying. Also a quick search indicates it might not work in shells other than Bash.

I could use interactive `cat`:

```bsh
$ cat | entr echo "command ran"
filename2
filename2
```

but again I have to do a newline each time, not much margin for error, and carefully enter <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> at the end.

A heredoc works similarly but involves bookend syntax.

```bsh
$ cat << EOF | entr echo "command ran"
> filename1
> filename2
> EOF
```

### one-liners:

I could also do `ls`, which looks nice at first glance:

```bsh
$ ls filename1 filename2 | entr echo "command ran"
```

But `ls` would strip out misspelled names, while `entr` validates and warns on improper names, and I'm worried about side-effects of calling ls in this way.

I could `echo` and pipe to `tr` before piping to `entr`:

```bsh
$ echo filename1 filename2 | tr " " "\n" | entr echo "command ran"
```

But I don't like having all the extra commands.

### The Question:

How do I write a short, elegant command that works in most (preferably all) shells? Syntax expected by posix would be ideal.

Comment: So how *exactly* would you like to specify files? A situation where we craft different methods, trying to fit your undisclosed subjective taste, does not correspond with the gist of the site. You should state your requirements first, e.g `frobnicate 'echo "command ran"' filename1 filename2` or `frobnicate filename1 filename2` (and `echo "command ran"` is fixed) or "I'd like to pick files from the current directory interactively". For now we know few syntaxes you don't like. What would you like?

Comment: If all you need are newline-separated names, maybe this will be ok:  `printf "%s\n" filename1 "filename with spaces 2" | entr echo "command ran"`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that should be in an answer

Answer (score 2):

Since `entr` appears to want each file on a separate line you're pretty limited.  You *have* to have each filename on a separate line.  Any attempt to make it a single line (eg your `tr` example) will fail if the separator character is part of a filename ("this is a filename").

I'd just do the simple

```
echo 'filename 1
filename2' | entr echo "command ran"
```